# How can I read a file in prolog and put in a list just a few words?

Tags: file, list, prolog

I must read results.txt that contains a tree consisting of:

ROOT (
 S(
   NP(..)
   NV(..)
  .
  .
 )
)

and other things that do not serve me,

how do I insert only "ROOT (...)" in a list?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite your question being vague, here is a snippet of working code. You'll need to adapt it to your actual requirement

```
tree(Tree) -->
    sym(Functor), "(", arguments(Args), ")",
    {Tree =.. [Functor|Args]}.

sym(S) -->
    [F], { sym_char(F) },
    sym_rest(Cs),
    !, { atom_codes(S, [F|Cs]) }.

sym_rest([C|Cs]) -->
    [C], { sym_char(C) },
    sym_rest(Cs).
sym_rest([]) --> [].

sym_char(F) :- F >= 0'A, F =< 0'Z .

arguments([A|Args]) --> argument(A), ",", arguments(Args).
arguments([A]) --> argument(A).
argument(A) --> tree(A) ; sym(A).

... --> [] ; [_], ... .
```

use with [phrase_from_file](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%27A.19.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/pio.html%27%29%29)/2 and cons in a list the term returned, here I show a test using phrase/2 instead.

```
?- phrase((..., tree(T), ...), " -- garbage -- A(X,Y,Z(A,B,C)) -- garbage --").
T = 'A'('X', 'Y', 'Z'('A', 'B', 'C')) .
```